# How to: jQuery/JS Dialog box with checkbox on a link with click event (to go to that link)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I've been asked for a simple solution to add to links on a blog that would pop-up a warning before going to that link. Only if you agree do you go on to that link. The first solution works fine (and I got it here):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_alert(node) {
    return confirm("some message here");
}
</script>
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return confirm_alert(this);">Click Me</a>
```

However, now I've been asked to have a checkbox in the pop-up that says something like "I understand" and then a button to continue. If it isn't checked or if they click outside the box (or the X close button if there is one), then it just goes back to the page they were on. If it IS checked and they click continue it goes to the URL on the link (as above).

Along with this, I need to set a browser cookie ONLY if the dialog is checked and continue hit. I've set cookie's in browser with JS before, but not attached to to an event like this, so I'm not sure how to do that either.

I've done many searches here and on the net in general and can't seem to find any examples that do this. I have found that there's no way to do this with a standard confirm dialog and would need to use jQuery and that's fine, but I still can't find an example.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't necessarily need jQuery for this.  You are correct though that you can not use `confirm`.  The code you would need however is pretty straight forward.  Just create a hidden `<div>` on the page that contains the message with the "I understand" checkbox.  Add an event on checkbox (or button) that will send them to the url if its checked.  Show this div when they click the link (with a `preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I guess I should of stated that I'm far from a programmer. While I can understand quite a bit, writing code from scratch is another story altogether. I get the hidden div part as this is done for modals, but you lost me on everything else.

Comment: I'll add an answer with what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this code (I just free typed it here).

In the HTML:

```
<div id="agreeModal">
  <input id="agree" type="checkbox" />
  <button id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
  <button id="btnContinue">Continue</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript  (in another file or in a `<script>` tag) :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var agreeUrl = '';

  // Get the links on the page
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  links.addEventListener('click', function( event ){
    event.preventDefault(); //stop it from following link
    agreeUrl = this.getAttribute('href');  // get the url
    document.getElementById('agreeModal').style.display='block';  //show Modal
  });

  var btnContinue = document.getElementById('btnContinue');
  btnContinue.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cb = document.getElementById('agree');
    if (cb.checked) { //if checkbox is checked goto url
      location.href= agreeUrl;
    }
  });

  var btnCancel = document.getElementById('btnCancel');
  btnCancel.addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //hide Modal
    document.getElementById('agreeModal').style.display='';
  });

});
```

Same code in jQuery:

```
(function( $ ){
 $(function(){

  var agreeUrl='';

  $('a').on('click', function( event ){
    event.preventDefault(); //stop it from following link
    agreeUrl = $(this).attr('href');  // get the url
    $('#agreeModal').show();  //show Modal
  });

  $('#btnContinue').on('click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('#agree').prop('checked')) { //if checkbox is checked goto url
      location.href= agreeUrl;
    }
  });

  $('#btnCancel').on('click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //hide Modal
    $('#agreeModal').hide();
  });

 });
})( jQuery);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant! The JS version gave me a "links.addEventListener is not a function" error, but the jquery version works a treat! There's a chance of multiple URL's on the page that need this pop-up so I added a class and added that ('a.popup') and it ignores all other links and gives me the checkbox/buttons on the ones with it. Thanks!